# Running a swift 3 app in the background

Tags: swift, macos

I am very new to Swift programming. I am making an app to fetch wifi information from only Mac OS devices. This app is supposed to run in the background. What kind of daemon process should I use to make this app run in the background? Also, I am trying to use location services, it does not work. It worked before but it suddenly stopped working, under System Preferences-> Location Services , I do not see my app anymore. I have done all the changes in info.plist but I can't seem to understand why it does not work.

Comment: @iOSAppDev Read the second sentence, I think OP is talking about Mac OS and not iOS.

Comment: I am talking about Mac OS only. Here is the info.plist file :

Comment: So is there no way to run an app in the background in Mac OS ?

Comment: See [Daemons and Services Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/Introduction.html).

Comment: I fixed the Location services problem, seems like I had to uncheck the Location box , under Capabilities->App Sandbox